# ionic tabs with static data

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and trying to use tab control in a view. The tab control has static text along with an icon. But when I try to run `ionic emulate android`, only tab control appear and switching to tabs doesn't display content.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <!-- Tab 1 content -->
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-location" icon-off="ion-ios-location-outline">
    <ion-nav-view>
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content>
           <i class="ion-bag"></i>Hello
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I have gone through examples on ionic site, but the examples are making use of templates to render content, which is overkill in my case.

**EDIT 1**:
I tried remove `ion-nav-view` and kept only `ion-view` but that too didn't work.

Comment: Please mark as correct if correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For static tabs, wrap the ion-content with an ion-pane.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <!-- Tab 1 content -->
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-location" icon-off="ion-ios-location-outline">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-content>
         <i class="ion-bag"></i>Hello
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```